# Android Camera custom zoom anywhere on the camera view

Tags: android, android-camera, zooming

Is there a way, in which I can select a focus area on the camera preview by touch gesture and zoom into that specific area?

Comment: can you do that with a normal camera? do you think that the camera lens move where you want?  or is it you that after applying zoom have to put the image in the middle of the field of view?

Comment: Let's say... you double click on the top right corner of the camera view.... The you should be able to zoom in 3x on the view, with point where you click noow in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: yes, you can.

If your camera supports video resolution higher than the preview area, zoom in can show more details. Often, it's not the case, and zoomed in picture will not look good.

Comment: I have been rambling across the Android Camera API, to find something, cannot get a clue...Please guide me in how can I get started. Where should I start looking into? Just to repeat the problem statemet....I have the camera preview open in front of me and let's say I double click on the top right corner of the screen, then my camera should zoom in to that area with the point (where I double tapped as the center)

Comment: Hi Alex.. Can you please give me some clues on how can I start on this problem...

Comment: Do you expect that the prevew will be frozen when you double click on the screen, so that the user can inspect the view? Or you want to continue live preview?

Comment: With live preview, it's much easier to move the device a bit than to deal with zoom-in in the cornerof the viewport.

Comment: :)... Agreed... But if I make a custom and want to do the jugulary with camera not moving....Do you think.. it is possible with current Andorid SDK's.....In last one week, I have searched enough to conclude NO...Your next response is the only hope :)...Thanks a lot

Comment: Android includes extensions thst involve operating external hardware, like servo- motors that will move your camera when necessary. If the camera is fixed, zooming in to peripheral area involves an extra challenge: the camera is often less accurate in the corner, and such distortions are very visible to human eye.

Comment: Any part of Android SDK that can help me get started??

Comment: _part of Android SDK_ - are you interested in operating external hardware? This is the [Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html)